# Find the IP address of an MQTT broker dynamically, in C

Tags: c, mqtt

I was wondering if there is a way to use a library in C, or some functionality in order to obtain dynamically the IP address of the broker that you need to connect to, instead of changing every time the IP address manually inside the code.

Comment: Why does the IP address change?

Comment: @tkausl Because I have several identical microcontrollers, which needs to be connected with different broker at a time. So every time I need to go to the code and configure the IP I want in order to connect the microcontroller with the proper broker.  It is one code that needs to be uploaded to all the microcontrollers, with the only difference is that I need to configure each time different IP, so I am trying to find a way to extract the IP dynamically.

Comment: And each of your micros needs a different broker?

Comment: Assuming you are in some private home network environment, can you define a name for the broker in the DHCP server of your DSL router? Depending in the router model, that name might be available via DNS. You could then use `broker.local` or similar instead of the IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information in the question to answer this correctly.

That said the following technologies exist specifically for allowing IP addresses to be changed.

1. Normal DNS, you assign a host name to the IP address either as an A record or a CNAME record. You then configure the client device with the hostname instead of the IP address and rely on the OS/Network Stack to do hostname to IP address resolution.
2. mDNS this is a local multicast version of DNS that only works on the same LAN (usually subnet). Again you should allocate the broker a hostname in the `.local` domain and reference this in the client. This will require the client to be configured with a mDNS resolver.
3. DNS SRV records with values of `_mqtt._tcp.domain`. the mosquitto library supports looking up SRV records when given the domain as the hostname.

Also rather than hardcoding the broker hostname/IP address in the code, you should probably store it in a flash variable that can be changed independently of the code.